# Django http 403 error with Django 1.8 and Python 3.4 under macos 10.10.5

Tags: python, django, http

I try this routine, use curl to send a post to server, and want it to return http body.

Command:

```
curl --data "hi server" http://127.0.0.1:8000/verification/activate/
```

Server Side:

```
def activate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse(request.body)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('please send a post http.')
```

The string, "hi server", should be return message. but I got this error:

```
[18/Aug/2015 03:16:34]"POST /verification/activate/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2629
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CSRF middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf) is activated by default in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting. This middleware returns `HTTP 403` in case the csrf token is missing in request body.

You can either remove `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` array in *settings.py* or use [`csrf_exempt()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator to disable csrf protection just for a single view:

*(Please note that the first option is strongly discouraged for security measures)*

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def activate(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Recommending the removal of CSRF protection wholesale is not advisable from a security standpoint.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Although it is not, it is still up developer's decision and, he has right to know it can be disabled wholesale.